# Is an input component calling `onChange` on initialization to set a default good practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have seen this pattern a few times am wondering if this is a best practice, or if there is another way.

Consider a dropdown selector component with props:

```
interface SelectProps {
   items: string[],
   value: string | null,
   onChange: (value: string) => void
}
```

The `Select` component has logic to determine the default value to determine which option to show if the value isn't set by default or set to a non-available value.

```
if (!value || !items.includes(value)) {
   const defaultOption = computeDefaultOption(items);
   onChange(defaultOption);
}
```

Is this a good practice?

The main pitfall I see in this pattern are conflicts between competing setters:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(null)

<Select items={itemSet1} value={state} onChange={setState} />
<Select items={itemSet2} value={state} onChange={setState} />
```

which could make behavior a unpredictable if `itemSet1` and `itemSet2` do not have the same items.

Comment: Feels like that initial reset would be the least of your problems in that last example, sharing the same state even with the _same_ items would be weird.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this pattern, but if you need to know a proper value, it makes sense. It does *change* after all, it sets a value other than it received.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a recommended practice to trigger a fake change in a controlled component like the Select component. If the value is controlled by the parent component, it should be passed as a prop and calculated within the parent component.

By having the Select component determine the default value and trigger a fake change, it creates a potential conflict with other setters. If multiple instances of the Select component have different item sets, unpredictable behavior could occur.

Instead, it is better to have the default value calculation done in the parent component and passed down to the Select component as a prop. This eliminates any potential conflict between competing setters and ensures that the value being set is the result of a real change.

Comment: How can you have the parent manage it if the computation used to select the default option is opaque? Do you have any sources for your answer, or is it just opinion? As is, it just rehashes my concerns from my question.